# Write a program that will form a matrix

Tags: javascript

It should look like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 0 1 2 3
2 1 0 1 2
3 2 1 0 1
4 3 2 1 0
```

I am using `for loop` with another nested loop but with no success. Here are my lame attempts to figure it out.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
              document.write(j);
        }
document.write(“<br>” + (i + 1));
}
```

Comment: `document.write` should be abandoned in favor of other write methods. Also make sure you don't overwrite the contents of an element with empty states. Instead concatenate a string. Than only after the string is constructed - place it into a desired target element- once.

Comment: Step through your code with a table to record the values of i and j. Watch what happens and think about how you can change it to fit the pattern you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each value of the matrix is the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) of the difference between `i` and `j` you can use [**Math.abs()**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_abs.asp) :

```js
function paintMatrix(n) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      result += " " + Math.abs(i - j);
    }
    result += "\n"
  }
  console.log(result);
}

paintMatrix(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this algorithm

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    document.write(Math.abs(j-i));
  }
  document.write('<br>')
}
```

Comment: Try rather to `str += Math.abs(j-i)` etc - and than only once (after all the loops) use document.someElement `innerHTML` or `insertAdjacentHTML` or some other form of string inclusion

Comment: question was about algorithm to form matrix. I just change sample from question according to issue